# Where should I be instantiating my "Ticket" to prevent them from all becoming the same price?

Tags: java

I have a program that sells tickets to events and in particular "Plays." The tickets start at a base value of 10.0 and are multiplied by a priceFactor. I have the price factor working appropriately, but the tickets all end up taking the value of the final ticket's price.

I have tried instantiating a Ticket object (Ticket tick = new Ticket(this);...because it takes a parameter of an Event) in the Event class and Play class's addTicket methods (stackoverflowerror) and in the Ticket constructor, but was unsuccessful. What I have noticed is that without adding any instantiations, my ticket objects serialNumbers still increment up, so I am unsure why all my tickets end up with the same price if* it is creating a new Ticket object.

```
public class Play extends Event {

    /**
     * Creates a Play object with the description and price factor.
     * 
     * @param description the description of the play
     * @param priceFactor the price factor for the play
     */
        public Play(String description, double priceFactor) {
            super(description, priceFactor);

        }  

    /**
     * Creates a play with the given description and a price factor of 1.0.
     * 
     * @param description the description of the play
     */
    public Play(String description) {
        this(description, 1.0);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a ticket to the list of tickets sold for this Play object. It also
     * adjusts the price factor.
     * 
     * @param ticket the Ticket object to be added
     * @return true iff the Ticket object could be added.
     * @throws NoSpaceException 
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addTicket(Ticket ticket) throws UnsupportedOperationException, NoSpaceException {

        double i = this.getPriceFactor();
        if (this.getTickets().size() < 3) {
            super.addTicket(ticket);
        }
        else if (this.getTickets().size() == 3) {
            super.setPriceFactor(i * 1.2);
            i = super.getPriceFactor();
            super.addTicket(ticket);
        }
        else if (this.getTickets().size() == 4) {
            super.setPriceFactor(i * 1.2);
            super.addTicket(ticket);
        }
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Returns a String representation.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Play" + " " + super.getEventId() + " " + super.getDescription() + " " + super.getPriceFactor();
    }
}

----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    public abstract class Event {
    private String description;
    protected int ticketsSold;
    private int eventId;
    private double priceFactor;
    private static int counter = 1;
    private static final int CAPACITY = 5;
    private ObservableList<Ticket> tickets = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * Stores the description and price factor and assigns a unique id to the event.
     * The constructor also allocates the array tickets.
     * 
     * @param description a description of this Play
     * @param priceFactor the price factor for this Play
     * 
     */
    public Event(String description, double priceFactor) {
        this.description = description;
        this.priceFactor = priceFactor;
        this.eventId = computeSerialNumber();
    }

    /**
     * Receives the description and stores that and a price factor of 1.0. Besides,
     * it assigns a unique id to the event. The constructor also allocates the array
     * tickets.
     * 
     * @param description a description of this Play
     * 
     */
    public Event(String description) {
        this(description, 1.0);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the unique id of the play
     * 
     * @return id of the play
     * 
     */
    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the tickets list
     * 
     * @return the tickets list
     */
    public ObservableList<Ticket> getTickets() {
        return tickets;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the price factor for the event.
     * 
     * @param priceFactor the new price factor
     */
    public void setPriceFactor(double priceFactor) {
        this.priceFactor = priceFactor;
    }

    /**
     * Computes and returns the total proceeds for this event.
     * 
     * @return total proceeds
     */

    public double getProceeds() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (Ticket t : tickets) {
            sum += t.getPrice();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    /**
     * Compares this Play with object. Follows the semantics of the equals method in
     * Object.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int hashcode() {
        return this.eventId;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the description of the Play object
     * 
     * @return description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the price factor
     * 
     * @return price factor
     */
    public double getPriceFactor() {
        return priceFactor;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for description
     * 
     * @param description the new description
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a unique serial number. This is a helper method.
     * 
     * @return serial number
     */
    private int computeSerialNumber() {
        int i = counter;
        counter++;
        return i;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a ticket to the list of tickets sold for this Play object.
     * 
     * @param ticket the Ticket object to be added
     * @return true iff the Ticket object could be added.
     * @throws NoSpaceException 
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException 
     */

    public boolean addTicket(Ticket ticket) throws UnsupportedOperationException, NoSpaceException {
        if (tickets.size() == CAPACITY)
            return false;
        else
            tickets.add(ticket);
            ticketsSold++;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a String representation of this Event object
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description + " " + eventId;
    }

}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public class Ticket {

    private static int counter = 1;
    private int serialNumber;
    private double price;
    private static double PRICE = 10.0;
    private Event event;

    /**
     * Creates a ticket for an event. An exception is thrown if there is no space.
     * 
     * @param event the event for which the ticket is being created.
     * @throws NoSpaceException
     */
    public Ticket(Event event) throws NoSpaceException, UnsupportedOperationException { 

            this.event = event;
            event.addTicket(this);
            this.serialNumber = computeSerialNumber();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the price of the ticket
     * 
     * @return ticket price
     */
    public double getPrice() {
        price = Ticket.PRICE * event.getPriceFactor();
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * Generates a String representation of the Ticket.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ticket serialNumber = " + serialNumber + ", " + "price =" + this.getPrice();
    }

    /*
     * Creates a serial number for the ticket.
     */
    private static int computeSerialNumber() {
        int i = counter;
        counter++;
        return i;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedOperationException, NoSpaceException {
        double a,b,c,d,e;

        Play p = new Play("p1", 1.0);
        Ticket tick = new Ticket(p);
        Ticket tick2 = new Ticket(p);
        Ticket tick3 = new Ticket(p);
        Ticket tick4 = new Ticket(p);
        Ticket tick5 = new Ticket(p);

        p.addTicket(tick);
        p.addTicket(tick2);
        p.addTicket(tick3);
        p.addTicket(tick4);
        p.addTicket(tick5);

        a = tick.getPrice();
        b = tick2.getPrice();
        c = tick3.getPrice();
        d = tick4.getPrice();
        e = tick5.getPrice();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Expected results for the tickets in order [10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.399]

Actual results [14.399, 14.399, 14.399, 14.399, 14.399]

Comment: Last time you asked this question, it was closed because you didn't provide a minimal reproducible example.  You still haven't provided a minimal reproducible example.   We cannot answer your question properly without that.

Comment: We *suspect* that the problem is that you are repeatedly adding the same `Ticket` object to the list.  But we can't be sure that that is happening (and why) unless you provide the minrep.  And if this is *not* what is happening, we can't work out what is *actually* happening .... without a minrep.

Comment: Would that be adding all parts of these respective classes? I went with all of the code that has to do with the Ticket.

Comment: *"Would that be adding all parts of these respective classes?"* - Not necessarily. All we need is sufficient code that 1) can be compiled and executed *by us*, and 2) will reproduce the problem you are talking about.  For example, you could write a test class with a `main` method that calls the relevant parts of this code in a way reproduces the problem.

Comment: It unfortunately is a GUI which is why I went with just the classes, but I will work on a main method now.

Comment: Event.addTicket(Ticket) looks dubious.

Comment: I can't run your example - I'm getting a stack overflow from bouncing between Event.addTicket, Ticket constructor, and Play.addTicket.

Comment: Delete the Ticket tick instantiation from the Event.addTIcket. I left it in just showing how I was trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to DerMolly's answer of bringing the pricefactor into the Ticket class, is to just calculate the price at creation, instead of on each getPrice:

```java
    public Ticket(Event event) throws NoSpaceException, UnsupportedOperationException { 

        this.event = event;
        event.addTicket(this);
        this.price = Ticket.PRICE * event.getPriceFactor();
        this.serialNumber = computeSerialNumber();

    }

    public double getPrice() {

        return price;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently all `Ticket` Objects hold a reference to their `Event` and get the `priceFactor` from there. Then you sometimes change the `priceFactor` in the `Event` and all `Ticket` Objects get the new `priceFactor` from their `Event`.

```
public double getPrice() {
    price = Ticket.PRICE * event.getPriceFactor();
    return price;
}
```

You could put the `priceFactor` (via Constructor or otherwise) into your `Ticket` Objects.

```
public class Ticket {

    private static int counter = 1;
    private int serialNumber;
    private double price;
    private static double PRICE = 10.0;
    private double priceFactor;
    private Event event;


    public Ticket(Event event, double priceFactor) throws NoSpaceException, UnsupportedOperationEtception { 
        this.event = event;
        this.priceFactor = priceFactor;
        event.addTicket(this);
        this.serialNumber = computeSerialNumber();
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        price = Ticket.PRICE * this.getPriceFactor();
        return price;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to set the `priceFactor` directly you could also copy it's value in the Constructor of `Ticket`

```
public class Ticket {

    private static int counter = 1;
    private int serialNumber;
    private double price;
    private static double PRICE = 10.0;
    private double priceFactor;
    private Event event;


    public Ticket(Event event) throws NoSpaceException, UnsupportedOperationEtception { 
        this.event = event;
        this.priceFactor = event.getPriceFactor;
        event.addTicket(this);
        this.serialNumber = computeSerialNumber();
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        price = Ticket.PRICE * this.getPriceFactor();
        return price;
    }
}
```